# Proof of a combinatorial equality

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a set of $n$ elements. Let $M$ be a $k$-multiset whose underlying set is $X$. We say $M$ to be of type $(c_1,\dots,c_k)$ if it has exactly $c_i$ distinct elements with multiplicity $i$, $1\leq i\leq k$. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^k ic_i=k$. Then it is not hard to see that the number of $k$-multisets with underlying set $X$ of type $(c_1,\dots,c_k)$ is
$$ \binom{n}{c_1+\cdots+c_k}\binom{c_1+\dots+c_k}{c_1,\dots,c_k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-c_1-\dots-c_k+1)}{c_1!\cdots c_k!}$$
Since total number of $k$-multisets with underlying set $X$ is $\frac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+k-1)}{k!}$, we must have
$$\sum_{(c_1,\dots,c_k):c_i\geq 0,\sum ic_i=k}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-c_1-\dots-c_k+1)}{c_1!\cdots c_k!}=\frac{n(n+1)\cdots (n+k-1)}{k!}$$
I have verified the equality for $k=1,2,3,4$ with the help of Mathematica, but I cannot find a proof for the general $k$.

Comment: So a proof by double counting is not enough?

Comment: @Phicar I prefer a non-combinatorial proof.